# jquery map return json object from mutiple sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var idk = $('#menu li').map(function (i, n) {

    var placeholder = $(n).attr('id')
    var content = $(n).find('.li2').attr('id');

    return //..

}).get().join(',');
```

}

I want to get something like this
{'a':1,'b':2,'c',3} where abc is come from placeholder, 123 is the content. What should I return using `map()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` gives you array of objects.

use `$.extend` to merge them into one object.

```
var arrayOfObjects = $('#menu li').map(function (i, n) {

    var placeholder = $(n).attr('id')
    var content = $(n).find('.li2').attr('id');
    var obj = {};
    obj[placeholder] = content;
    return obj;
});
// arrayOfObjects = [{a : 1}, {b : 2}, {c : 3}]

var obj = $.extend.apply(null, arrayOfObjects);
// obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comment: I got unexpected token : at     return { placeholder : content };

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point of what you're trying to do, but I don't think you need map. Why not just something like this?

```
var listItems = $('#menu li');
var map = {};

for (var i = 0, length = listItems.length; i < length; i++) {
  var listItem = listItems[i];

  map[listItem.attr('id')] = listItem.innerText;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vahija/1/edit